# Can a Linking Verb be a Phrasal Verb?

Tags: grammar

I'm aware of what phrasal verbs and the fact they are typically accompanied by a word like up, down, or in in order to add meaning to the verb. But, in the sentence: **The subject is whom or what the sentence is about**, is 'is about' a phrasal verb? I know the object pronoun whom here should be the object of the preposition about, but isn't the word 'about' here linked to the verb 'is'? If so, then shouldn't whom be changed to who? If so, are there any other examples of linking phrasal verbs?

I may be completely wrong on this, I am just a bit perplexed and curious to know. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not. I see where you're coming from, but _about_ is just a preposition, not the particle of a phrasal verb. In this case, it's the head of the predicate prepositional phrase _be about `X`_, where `X` is what gets turned into _what_ or _who_ and moved to the front of the clause by _Wh_-Question Formation. (The _whom_ is only required when a preposition is pied-piped to the front along with _who_.)

Comment: And as to the question in the title, the answer is no. Auxiliary verbs are just auxiliary verbs, not phrasal verbs. But they can occur with phrasal verbs (_He's looking up the word_), and they must occur with non-verbal predicates, like predicate nouns (_He's a doctor_), predicate adjectives (_He's very good at this_), and, as here, predicate propositional phrases (_It's all about respect_).

Comment: Thanks! I do have another question though. In a prepositional phrase right after a linking verb, is that prep phrase acting like an adjective or adverb? I'm tempted to think the latter mainly because it doesn't make much sense as an adjective. However, if that is the case, then wouldn't that imply linking verbs don't really need a complement or predicate adjective? After all, an adverb is not either of those. Thus, one could argue, "He is" or the imperative "Be!" on its own is a complete sentence. Am I right on that?

Comment: It's acting like a prepositional phrase. A predicate prepositional phrase. Also a Verb phrase, starting with the _be_. You seem to assume that there is a fixed and limited set of categories to which things can be assigned. Not true, alas. Any kind of word or phrase can be a predicate; only the prototype predicate -- verbs -- inflect for tense, so some appropriately inflected form of _be_ is required for all other non-verbal predicates, including all phrases and clauses except verb phrases, which must already start with either a modal or a tensed verb.

Comment: "Donald turned out stupid."

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're saying (mainly the very last part). Is a predicate prepositional phrase an adjective or adverb? May you please explain further? Thank you.

Comment: Phrasal verbs are verbs with some special meaning, sometimes they deviate from their literal meaning. You can see [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76208/3463) for more info. Not exact answer to your question, but some good info.

Comment: In your example, the preposition "about" is said to be 'stranded' since it is missing its complement, though it's understood as the phrase "whom or what". Since the phrase is complement of a prep, the pronoun should strictly speaking be "whom", but that's a bit stuffy and most people would say "who".

Answer (score -2):

The distinguishing of some structures as **verb + prepositional phrase** or **multi-word verb + object** is notoriously difficult, and perhaps contentious. But 'be about [...]' in this sense is probably best considered insufficiently cohesive to be analysed as a MWV (though 'address', 'cover' are single-verb synonyms).

An example of a linking MWV is 'turn into [...]' (in the 'become', not the driving, sense).

Comment: An explanation of what you perceive the error to be?